trying to install frappe hrms in windows local server and havimg error in env
I m trying to set frappe hrms in windows local server git bash and i install frappe-bench using bash command but when i try to install hrms i have env error this is my error

ROHAN@Rohan MINGW64 /c/hrms
$ bench init frappe-bench
User ID: ROHAN
Setting Up Environment
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
ERROR: venv cannot be found
$ None env
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ROHAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\bench\commands\make.py", line 75, in init
    init(
  File "C:\Users\ROHAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\bench\utils\render.py", line 105, in wrapper_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ROHAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\bench\utils\system.py", line 101, in init
    bench.setup.env(python=python)
  File "C:\Users\ROHAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\bench\utils\render.py", line 126, in wrapper_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ROHAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\bench\bench.py", line 362, in env
    self.run(f"{venv} env", cwd=self.bench.name)
  File "C:\Users\ROHAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\bench\bench.py", line 48, in run
    return exec_cmd(cmd, cwd=cwd or self.cwd, _raise=_raise)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ROHAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\bench\utils\__init__.py", line 174, in exec_cmd
    return_code = subprocess.call(spl_cmd, cwd=cwd, universal_newlines=True, env=env)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ROHAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ROHAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\ROHAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

ERROR: There was a problem while creating frappe-bench


Can anyone help me to solve this error

The error looks like due either Python and the virtual environment not installed or not properly set up.
Best way is to ensure python compatible with Frappe that is 3.10+ is installed, added to the PATH.
Ensure venv is installed. If python is installed, below command to should help with it:
python -m ensurepip --default-pip
python -m pip install virtualenv

Also, see if MINGW64 is the culprit. Try using default windows terminal or WSL.
